# Can you characterize a recommended experimental technique for measuring the thermal diffusivity of metals?

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, thermal-conductivity

It is surprising that the $\alpha$ thermal diffusivity is still undefined in 3D geometry.
The current ad hoc scalar definition $\alpha$=K/$\rho$ S in normal conventions is not the best.
Currently the ONLY accepted definition for thermal diffusivity α is the scalar α=K/ρ S. But the question is whether we can define thermal diffusivity as the ratio of the heat left through the material to the heat per unit of volume stored in the material per unit time. In the latter case, we can design an experiment to measure α directly in one step rather than in 3 measurement steps (K,ρ,S).

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! The density $\rho$ and specific heat $c$ are scalars, so it would seem that this question is equivalent to asking about experimental techniques for measuring the anisotropic thermal conductivity $k$. Then one can work with the heat equation as $\nabla\cdot(k\nabla T)=\rho c \dot T$. Would you agree?

Comment: Chemomechanics 5
 Thank you for your exact answer.
I agree with you that currently the ONLY accepted definition for thermal diffusivity α is the scalar α=K/ρ S.
But the question is whether we can define thermal diffusivity as the ratio of the heat left through the material to the heat per unit volume stored in the material per unit time.
In the latter case, we can design an experiment to measure  α directly in one step rather than 3 measurement steps (K,ρ ,S).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Angstrom’s method. You apply periodic heat source or an impulse to the end of a long bar and measure temperatures at different positions along the length of the bar as a function of time. If I remember correctly Essentially the diffusivity is related to the phase of the thermal wave.

Comment: Thank you for your exact answer.
If we consider the Angstrom method of the long bar, we see that it is a one-dimensional experiment and that the thermal diffusivity α is always undefined in 3D geometry. The scalar definition α=K/ρ S used in this experiment is not the best. But the question remains whether we can define thermal diffusivity as the ratio of the heat left through the material to the heat per unit volume stored in the material per unit time. In the latter case, we can also design a 2D and 3D experiment to measure α directly in a single step.

Comment: Yes, I have seen papers where it has been done in at least 2D. I believe that the thermal conductivity is also extracted with that type of measurement. I think the issues experimentally are needing a better understanding of boundary conditions. But even the angstrom method is tricky to implement.

Comment: For example why not put a periodic heat source in the center of a sphere and measure the thermal wave in a similar way?  Experimentally it would be a little difficult, but the data could probably be obtained. Again small signals and need a large sphere.

Comment: I may be missing the point of your question. Thermal conductivity, heat capacity etc are useful for other purposes. In general thermal measurements are tricky and hard to do well.

Comment: Maybe a better technique for you to look at would be the the 3 omega technique. The thermal diffusion time can be extracted. That depends on the thermal diffusivity. Most often people use it to measure thermal conductivity, but you can also get the diffusivity. There are also some laser flash and pump probe techniques but 3omega is actually pretty good for some situations. Although if you are interested in metals it is less complicated with lower thermal conductivity insulating materials.

Answer (score 0):

The thermal diffusivity α is still undefined in 3D geometry. The current ad hoc scalar definition α=K/ρ S in normal conventions is not the best. Currently, the ONLY accepted definition for thermal diffusivity is the scalar α=K/ρ S

One can reason that the density ρ and the specific heat S are scalars, so it would seem logical that this question should be confused with the experimental techniques of measuring anisotropic thermal conductivity k where one can work with heat in a way different.
It is true that currently the ONLY accepted definition for thermal diffusivity α is the scalar α=K/ρ S. But the question is whether we can define thermal diffusivity as the ratio of the heat left through the material to the heat per unit volume stored in the material per unit time. In the latter case, we can design an experiment to measure α directly in one step rather than in 3 measurement steps (K,Roh ,S).
If we consider the Angstrom method of measuring the heat distribution along a long thin rod or the 3 Omega technique in radial coordinates, we see that both are a one-dimensional experiment and the thermal diffusivity used is always the scalar α=K/ρ S.In other words, we turn in a vicious circuit.
But a related question arises,
i- Why heat PDE  with Dirichlet BC cannot be resolved in 2D and 3D geometric space ii- is there a maximum value for the separation constant equal to log 2. That is the minimum and maximum values ​​of PDE heat separation constant with Dirichlet BC are zero and Log 2.
iii-Whetherif we can define thermal diffusivity as the ratio of the heat left through the material to the heat per unit volume stored in the material per unit time. In the latter case, one can design an experiment to measure D in 3 dimensions directly in one step rather than in 3 measurements -
In the latter case, two α,s can be defined, one microscopic for a point in space and the other macroscopic for the whole of the body or of the heated/cooled object made up of the material to be tested under consideration.
Moreover, there should be a mathematical physical relationship between the two α,s, which is the role of the so-called B transition matrix chains.
Obviously, we need a better understanding of Dirichlet boundary conditions where modified Diriclet BCs are treated as source/sink terms rather than lifeless BCs.
Here we can prove that D = Log{2} -Log(1.+RO}.. where RO is the entry element of the main diagonal of the transition matrix itself (RO element of [0, 1]) Physically speaking RO is equal to the thermal velocity Vth.dt/mean free path mfp and dt is the temporal jump.

NB: The 3 elements i,ii,iii are explained in a previous question: In the partial differential equation of heat diffusion, is it true that the minimum and maximum values ​​of the separation constant are zero and log 2?
which is closed and goes its golden way to be deleted.
The above theoretical processing shows that the time rise/fall curves in the heating/cooling curve are exponential with the exponent D/L^2 and hence the half value of the time T1/2 is given by,
T1/2=Log(2).L^2/α
where we extract α as,
α=(0.697)^-1. L^2 /T1/2 m^2 s^-1 . . . . (1)
We experimentally tested Equation 1 to find the thermal diffusivity of 10 cm cubes of high purity Egyptian aluminum alloy and high purity Russian carbon steel alloys.
The resistence thermometers used were TP 300 for the temperature range -50 to 300 C with an error less than or equal to 0.5 C.
The experimental results and the calcuation of α using Equation 1 were approximately as follows,
Aluminum alloy: T1/2= 380 s and thermal diffusivity α=3.78E-5 m^2 s^-1
Steel alloy T1/2= 720 s and thermal diffusivity α=1.99E-5 m^2 s^-1